# Is blue corrosion on components other than the battery ever normal?

Tags: corrosion

I've been troubleshooting a problem with my truck for a few days now and just noticed this on a component behind the throttle body. Someone told me this is the accelerator pump.

I haven't noticed blue corrosion like this on any other part of my vehicle except the battery terminals and I'm wondering how this could happen and if it could be affecting the component.[image: corrosion]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not chemist, but to my knowledge, green corrosion is usually a sign copper is present in the alloy. While corrosion isn't a good thing, I don't think it is abnormal given the right materials.

Comment: Copper ( brass  and bronze), green to blue depending on what is causing the corrosion.

Comment: So what is the problem?